How do I book a bus ticket with Comati PSG?
Recently I found out about the bus company Comati PSG which runs buses all the way from Sweden to Romania and makes intermediate stops in various countries between those. However, looking at their website, I can't seem to figure out how to actually book any route. I can select the departure stop where the list is properly populated with all kinds of destinations, but not the destination stop where the list only has the options "TO" and "Choose departure town".
I can also book journeys with them through FlixBus' booking interface, but they don't show all itineraries — if I search for my particular preferred one (Stockholm to Brno) I only get some FlixBus routes with two transfers. This is despite that if I choose a longer route (Stockholm to anywhere between Arad and Bucharest), Comati does show up and I can clearly see that my desired stop is in the list of stops on the FlixBus website (note that you have to choose a Monday or Friday).
With this in mind, what ways are there to book journeys with Comati PSG that allow selecting any given journey with them?

I got the Comati site to work as intended on mobile, maybe try that

I was able to select your desired trip on the Comati site in Firefox. Seems like you happened to hit some server issues when you tried.

For me, it looks like it works when you use the version in Romanian but not the one in English (or any of the other languages, actually). There's a bug in the translated versions which breaks the site.

@jcaron Thanks, that worked!

@jcaron Do you think you could write this as an answer to the question so I can accept it?

@Newbyte go ahead and write an answer with your experience:-)

It turns out as pointed out by @jcaron in the comments of my post that this just is a bug with the translated versions of the website. If you use the Romanian version instead of the other languages (e.g. English, Norwegian, Swedish), after entering your origin stop the destination drop-down menu will  be filled in with available destinations — including my desired route of Stockholm-Brno.

Please accept this answer, (or a better one if posted) when the option opens.
